# Salvar background e um Text em um banco de dados

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, gridview

Meu projeto é simples, um grid view, com vários botões, e no clique deles abre uma popup com 3 opções e no clique delas, seta um texto e um background no botão, mas quando saio da activity e entro eles , não estão lá, queria uma ajuda com banco de dados, para salvar isso.

```
botaoDoGridView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final PopupMenu pn = new PopupMenu(CalendarActivity.this, bt11);
        pn.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, pn.getMenu());
        pn.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {@Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.primeiro:
                    bt11.setText("HIDRATAR");
                    bt11.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.fundohidra));

                    return true;
                case R.id.segundo:
                    bt11.setText("NUTRIÇÃO");
                    bt11.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.fundonutri));
                    return true;
                case R.id.terceiro:
                    bt11.setText("RECONS");
                    bt11.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.fundorecon));
                    return true;
                case R.id.quarto:
                    bt11.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.desligar));
                    Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this, "Etapa Finalizada,Aguarde entre 48 a 72 horas para ir pra proxima Etapa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
        pn.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Dá uma lida [nessa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485) página

Comment: desculpa mesmo mano... não sabia disso, ja ate troquei

Comment: De boa, uma dica: coloca 4 espaços na frente do seu código para ele ficar melhor formatado

Comment: vlw mano <3 , vou publicar o app em alguns dias, e isso é o ultimo passo, preciso de ajuda kkk ,  falta só salvar esse background e texto do botao ,pra quando sair da activity e entrar eles aind estiverem la

Comment: Cara, a implementação de um banco não é tão trivial assim para se colar numa resposta. Dá uma estudada, não é complicado, e refaça a pergunta se empacar em alguma parte durante a implementação. Se o seu gridview não for muito dinâmico (entra e sai item o tempo todo), pode guardar as opções dos botões em SharedPreferences, que é uma implementação bem mais simples

Comment: Como sao poucos dados e algo basico, por que tu nao salva isso em um `SharedPreferences` ? Irá persistir da mesma forma.

Comment: eu tentei por agora mesmo no shared  e deu fail , kkk primeira tentativa lose..

Comment: luan gabriel , tem contato por whats app?  algum grupo ?

Comment: @ClehSilvah da uma olhada na nova arquitetura do Android, ficou muito bom e rápido de trabalhar com persistência de dados. Classe Room
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Comment: mandem numero do whats app ???